# Web scraping suddenly stopped working

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am going to start off by saying that my knowledge of XML is pretty minimal.

I promise you than until 2 or 3 days ago the following code worked perfectly:

```
library("rvest")
url<-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_United_Kingdom_general_election"
H<-read_html(url)
table<-html_table(H, fill=TRUE)
Z<-table[1]; Z1<-Z[[1]]
```

Which then allowed me to get on and do what I wanted, extracting the first table from that web page and putting it in data frame `Z1`. However, this has suddenly stopped working and I keep getting the error message:

```
Error in if (length(p) > 1 & maxp * n != sum(unlist(nrows)) & maxp * n !=  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

When I look at `H` it seems no longer to be a list and now looks like this:

```
{xml_document}
<html class="client-nojs" lang="en" dir="ltr">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
[2] <body class="mediawiki ltr sitedir-ltr mw-hide-empty-elt ns-0 ns-subject  ...
```

> 

It is clearly failing at `html_table`.

I really don't know where to start with this at all.

Comment: Am I not right in thinking that even if the table on the page had changed html_table should still have been able to parse it? I checked changes on the page over the period and they were minor editorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you missed a step in parsing out the table nodes before the html_table function.

```
library("rvest")
url<-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_next_United_Kingdom_general_election"
H<-read_html(url)
tables<-html_nodes(H, "table")
Z1<-html_table(tables[1], fill = TRUE)[[1]]
```

Comment: that seems to work. My recall is that when I first tried to do this I was using the tables method but ended up with the code I posted. This definitely did work until a few days ago. I have checked and the code has not been amended for months. Oh well. Thank you.